# glm; log link of the original target vs identity link of logged target

Tags: r, glm

Maybe this is a pretty basic question, but why are the results different? FACE are some numeric values and logFACE is log(FACE). I am confused why the coefficients would be different, even directions of some of them.

```
f1 <- as.formula(paste("FACE ~", paste(col.selection, collapse = "+")))
glm1 <-  glm(formula = f1, data = df.train, family = gaussian(link = "log"))
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(glm1)


f2 <- as.formula(paste("logFACE ~", paste(col.selection, collapse = "+")))
glm2 <- glm(formula = f2, data = df.train, family = gaussian(link = "identity"))
par(mfrow=c(2,2))
plot(glm2)

summary(glm1)
summary(glm2)
```

**Plot of glm1**
[image: glm1]

**Plot of glm2**
[image: glm2]

```
> coefficients(glm1)
(Intercept)      GENDER         AGE     MARSTAT   EDUCATION       NUMHH   logINCOME  logCHARITY     AGEdiff 
 5.71033133  2.28651820  0.01928597 -1.07200187  0.05477547 -0.05567484 -0.13955743  0.77219423 -0.26585280 
> coefficients(glm2)
(Intercept)      GENDER         AGE     MARSTAT   EDUCATION       NUMHH   logINCOME  logCHARITY     AGEdiff 
 3.95245904  0.87686820 -0.01206955  0.02667678  0.18357079  0.24466946  0.35963195  0.11596153 -0.05240633
```

Comment: Where are the plots? The reason why there are differences is likely that you use levels in the first case and logs in the second case. This gives you different coefficients.

Comment: The link function is applied to the parameter, not to the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you transform the response values by log, the predicted values are in log, hence residuals calculated, fitting etc is done in that scale. For example, we regress log(mpg) against am in mtcars:

```
fit = glm(log(mpg) ~ am, data=mtcars,family=gaussian())
summary(fit$fitted.values)
Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  2.817   2.817   2.817   2.958   3.163   3.163
```

For log-linked GLM gaussian, the response values mpg are expected to be exp(a*am + b):

```
fit = glm(mpg ~ am, data=mtcars,family=gaussian(link="log"))
summary(fit$fitted.values)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  17.15   17.15   17.15   20.09   24.39   24.39
```

So your responses are not log transformed, hence the residuals and fitting are done in this scale.

The coefficients are then different..

Comment: Thank you! So it seems the plot(glmmodel) are not so useful with log link GLMs?

Comment: You are welcome! Hmm you are referring to your plots? for glm2, where you log transform, the qqplot and residual vs fit plots look better right?

Comment: I'm still learning, so maybe my question is not something that makes sense.:) Thanks again!

Comment: Haha no problem. Ok short answer is, yes, transform your response using a log if it gives you something close to a normal distribution.